# passing pointer to change its value but stay still

Tags: c++, pointers, null

passing pointer to change its value but stay still

I am working on C++ with allegro library.

there is draw_tiles function.

```
void draw_tiles(def_small_world * s_world,BITMAP * dest){
    BITMAP *TileMap=NULL; 

    loadTilemap(s_world->tilemap,TileMap); 
    for(int y = 0;y<SIGHTY*2+1;y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0;x<SIGHTX*2+1;x++)
        {
            pasteTile(s_world->tile[y][x].kind,TileMap,dest,x,y);
        }
    }

}
```

and loadTilemap function.

```
void loadTilemap(int i,BITMAP * tileLayer){
    char c[128];
    sprintf(c,TILEPATHFORMAT,i);
    tileLayer= load_bitmap(c,NULL);
}
```

I expect

following code change TileMap to points somewhere

```
loadTilemap(s_world->tilemap,TileMap);
```

but after loadTilemap, the TileMap variable stay still.

the following code works very well

```
char c[128];
sprintf(c,TILEPATHFORMAT,i);
tileLayer= load_bitmap(c,NULL);
```

tileLayer points 0x003f93f8

How to fix my code to TileMap points return value of load_bitmap?

Comment: What is the return type of load_bitmap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the pointer by value, so a copy of the pointer is created. Inside `loadTilemap`, you are assigning a new value to the copy of the pointer - but that doesn't affect the original pointer.

Try passing the pointer by reference by changing the `loadTilemap` function signature to this:

```
void loadTilemap(int i,BITMAP *& tileLayer);
```

Comment: +1 for reference to a pointer instead of pointer to a pointer - this is C++, we have references.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a pointer to pointer to achieve that:

```
void loadTilemap(int i,BITMAP ** tileLayer){
   char c[128];
   sprintf(c,TILEPATHFORMAT,i);
   *tileLayer= load_bitmap(c,NULL); 
}

loadTilemap(s_world->tilemap, &TileMap);
```

That's assuming `TileMap` is of type `BITMAP *`.

Alternatively, you could simply return the `BITMAP*` pointer as a result of `loadTilemap`:

```
 BITMAP* loadTilemap(int i,BITMAP * tileLayer){
   char c[128];
   sprintf(c,TILEPATHFORMAT,i);
   return load_bitmap(c,NULL); 
}

TileMap = loadTilemap(s_world->tilemap, TileMap);
```

This would allow you to get rid of `tileLayer` parameter altogether, as you don't seem to be using it for anything else in `loadTileMap` (i.e. it's only an output parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void loadTilemap(int i,BITMAP ** tileLayer){
    char c[128];
    sprintf(c,TILEPATHFORMAT,i);
    *tileLayer = load_bitmap(c,NULL);
}


loadTilemap(s_world->tilemap, &TileMap);
```

The problem was that you pass the pointer to the `BITMAP` by value. To get the new pointer value out of `loadTilemap`, you have to pass it by reference.

**EDIT:**

On the other hand: why don't you just return the pointer to the newly created `BITMAP`?

```
BITMAP * loadTilemap(int i* tileLayer){
    char c[128];
    sprintf(c,TILEPATHFORMAT,i);
    return load_bitmap(c,NULL);
}

...

TileMap = loadTilemap(s_world->tilemap);
```